# Building app for Google Action and Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-assist-api

I am building app for both Google assistant and Alexa. I would like to develop all my logic in one web service and keep it in one codebase. What's the best practice here ? I see that https://www.jovo.tech looks promising

Comment: Hey there, Jan here, one of the founders of Jovo. Are there any specific best practices you're looking for? Also, here is a list of tutorials and courses: https://www.jovo.tech/learn